# Throw exception form override method without exception defined on org method interface

Tags: java, exception, eclipse-emf

I'm extending the class RecordingCommand from org.eclipse.emf.transaction.RecordingCommand; I need to override protected method `doExecute()`, the method definition does not contain any exception to throw but there is option that inside my code I have and exception and I want to catch it and raise it up, how should I handle this kind of exception, here I throw the message `e` but I'm not sure that this is the right way to do that.

I hope you will understand the issue since **I think it more sophisticated that just throw E**

i.e.throw the exception

```
@Override 
protected void doExecute() {
    try { 
        //my logic
   } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always throw an `UncheckedException` from a method, which need not be declared in the `throws` clause.

So, you  wrap your exception in any unchecked exception like that extends [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) or even `RuntimeException` itself.

```
try {
    //my logic
} catch(Exception e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

And just for the sake of completeness, it is a bad idea to have a single `catch` block for `Exception`, which will catch all the exceptions. Rather you should have `catch` block for specific type of exception your method may throw.

Comment: +1 Or any other `Exception` even custom `Exception` if that extends `RuntimeException`.